# Character frequency in a string (Python 3.9)

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, python-3.9, charactercount

How can you count the characters (characters frequency) in a string without using if, while or for?

Comment: `'aaabbc'.count('a')` gives `3`

Comment: string = "abcdefa" string.count("a")

Comment: At some level, there will be a need for/while to iterate the string. And an if statement to count a single character

Comment: iterate through all unique characters in string  using `for char in set(your_string): print(your_string.count(char))`

Answer (score 0):

You can use Counter, it returns a dictionary with character as a key and its frequency as its value.

```
from collections import Counter
x = "abcdasbdd"
print(Counter(x))
```

**Output**

```
Counter({'d': 3, 'a': 2, 'b': 2, 'c': 1, 's': 1})
```